# Laravel Eloquent Query Building

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, php-5.4

My current query is

```
select * from `users` where `group_id` = 1 and ((select count(*) from `works` inner join `user_work` on `works`.`id` = `user_work`.`work_id` where `user_work`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `work_duration_id` >= 3) >= 1)
```

For this query I have written following eloquent method in laravel 4.2 and it is working fine

```
$u = User::where('group_id', '=', 1);    
$u = $u->where(function($m) use($minWorkDuration,$searchCriteria){
     $m = $m->whereHas('work', function($q) use($minWorkDuration){
          $q->where('work_duration_id', '>=', $minWorkDuration );
     });
});
```

But I want to change in my query little bit and this is

```
select * from `users` where `group_id` = 1 and ((select count(*) from `works` inner join `user_work` on `works`.`id` = `user_work`.`work_id` where `user_work`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and (SELECT SUM(`work_duration_id`) from `works` group by `user_id`) >= 3) >= 1)
```

If I want to write this query then what will be in eloquent method. If anybody is there please suggest me how to write this query in eloquent method in laravel 4.2.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace inner line with $q->where(DB::raw("SELECT SUM(`work_duration_id`) from `works` group by `user_id`"), '>=', $minWorkDuration );

Comment: Yes I have tried in this way but it's giving error. I need the query like 
`and (SELECT SUM(`work_duration_id`) from `works` group by `user_id`) >= 3)` 
After replacing as you told it's coming like this way that's why error is showing
`and SELECT SUM(`work_duration_id`) from `works` group by `user_id` >= 3)`

Comment: query building ain't for complex queries.

Comment: Thanks @kamlesh.bar I have done it in your way with a little change `$q->where(DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(work_duration_id) from works group by user_id)"), '>=', $minWorkDuration );`

Comment: @user3676972 yes you are right i forgot () around select statement.